# Help with join query and return limit

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables in my database - gl_weather_locations and gl_weather_data.

[image: location table]
[image: location records]
[image: data table]
[image: data records]

I need to select location name, latitude and longitude from the locations table, then get only the most recent set of records for the corresponding lat/long in the data table - there can be multiple sets, as the database is populated from a web service that's updated every 2 hours. We need to keep archival data, so we can't keep only the most recent set of records, we need to keep all of them. But I'm a little confused as to how to limit my query to only the most recent set (there are multiples of 3 data records for each location - one for wind speed, one for wind direction, and one for wave height - we need to get the most recent of all three.)

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT l.location_name, l.location_lat, l.location_long, d.weather_type, 
       d.weather_value, d.weather_unit
FROM gl_weather_locations l
LEFT JOIN gl_weather_data d ON l.location_lat = d.weather_lat
```

(In our case, we're working with a limited number of locations and it's absolutely confirmed that we do not have more than one location with the exact same latitude, so we can safely do the join on only the latitude, rather than needing to also compare longitude.)

I'm confused as to how I can make sure I only get the most recent set of records for each latitude. If it helps, the weather_time field is identical for all of the records in a set (i.e. we have 10 locations, 3 records per location per run of the web service, so we have 30 records with identical values in weather_time.) Could I somehow use that in an order by or group by or something?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have analytics (ROW_NUMBER, DENSE_RANK), which is what you'd typically use for requests like these.  There are numerous similar questions tagged with "greatest-n-per-group" and "mysql"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd FROM (via SQL-Select) should get you on a per lat/long, the maximum respective time per each category.  Then, the overall query links the locations to that (MaxTimes) alias, then re-joins to the weather data based on whatever the max time matching the respective classification unit being tested for.  If you get any NULL values, you can just wrap those columns as    NVL( whatever_column,  '' ) as ResultColumn

```
select WLoc.ID,
       WLoc.Location_Name,
       WLoc.Location_Lat,
       WLoc.Location_Long,
       IFNULL( MaxTimes.WindDirTime, '' ) WindDirTime,       
       IFNULL( MaxTimes.WindSpdTime, '' ) WindSpdTime,       
       IFNULL( MaxTimes.WaveHeightTime, '' ) WaveHeightTime,       
       IFNULL( ByWindDir.Weather_Unit, '' ) WindDirection,       
       IFNULL( ByWindDir.Weather_Value, '' ) WindDirValue,       
       IFNULL( ByWindSpd.Weather_Unit, '' )  SpeedUnit,       
       IFNULL( ByWindSpd.Weather_Value, '' )  WindSpeed,       
       IFNULL( ByWaveHeight.Weather_Unit, '' )  WaveUnit,       
       IFNULL( ByWaveHeight.Weather_Value, '' )  WaveHeight
  from
     gl_weather_locations WLoc
        left join (select weather_lat,
                          weather_long,
                          max( case when weather_type = "Wind Direction" then weather_time end ) WindDirTime,
                          max( case when weather_type = "Wind Speed" then weather_time end ) WindSpdTime,
                          max( case when weather_type = "Wave Height" then weather_time end ) WaveHeightTime
                      from
                          gl_weather_data
                      group by 
                          1, 2 ) MaxTimes
             on WLoc.Location_Lat = MaxTimes.Weather_Lat
            and WLoc.Location_Long = MaxTimes.Weather_Long

                 left join gl_weather_data ByWindDir
                    on MaxTimes.weather_lat = ByWindDir.weather_lat
                    and MaxTimes.weather_long = ByWindDir.weather_long
                    and MaxTimes.WindDirTime = ByWindDir.weather_time
                    and ByWindDir.weather_type = "Wind Direction"

                 left join gl_weather_data ByWindSpd
                    on MaxTimes.weather_lat = ByWindSpd.weather_lat
                    and MaxTimes.weather_long = ByWindSpd.weather_long
                    and MaxTimes.WindSpdTime = ByWindSpd.weather_time
                    and ByWindSpd.weather_type = "Wind Speed"

                 left join gl_weather_data ByWaveHeight
                    on MaxTimes.weather_lat = ByWaveHeight.weather_lat
                    and MaxTimes.weather_long = ByWaveHeight.weather_long
                    and MaxTimes.WaveHeightTime = ByWaveHeight.weather_time
                    and ByWaveHeight.weather_type = "Wave Height"
```

The first FROM table is your list of master locations... by doing a LEFT JOIN, you are telling the SQL, no matter if I have a time-stamp match on the right side, show me all locations.

Next, is the PreQuery for MaxTimes.  Think of this sub-query as pre-gathering the maximum time per lat/long, PER respective TYPE of measurement reported via the MAX( case when... ) As FinalColumnName.  So, on each record, it will only qualify for ONE of these case entries, and if found, get the max of that column's time.

So, now, you have a list of locations, and left joined to a subquery MaxTimes joined on their respective LAT/LONG.  Now, the MaxTimes query is doing THREE left joins back to the measurements data, for each measurement respectively, so I've aliased them on what their purpose was for .. hence ByWindDir, ByWindSpd and ByWaveHeight.  The left join, like the others is based on the Lat/Long, its proper type ("Wind Direction", "Wind Speed", or "Wave Height") respectively, AND it has the same matching time OF that category.

The nice thing of this query is that if you have your times to a single lat/long location that are off, even by seconds (ie: Wind Direction is 11:58:02 and Wind Speed is 11:58:05 and Wave Height = 11:58:54, it will still respect each unique measurement's max time.

Finally, the field list... to tack on all for one row across, I'm getting the obvious details... Since each table was joined to represent its own "stuff", I have the column names represent the CONTEXT...  Hope this helps your understanding of this query... Take one part at a time and find what links to what.

Comment: OK, I'm scared now... I just tried to run this and got an error: Unknown column 'MaxTimes.weather_type' in 'on clause'. MaxTimes.weather_type exists in three places in the code, but I since I don't really understand the query itself I have no idea where to look for what's going wrong.

Comment: @EmmyS, fixed it...  I even created these table structures and sample data in my MySQL.  In the left joins, for the respective weather_types, I had wrong alias from copy\paste and needed to change to their respective ByWindDir, ByWindSpd, ByWaveHeight of their joins.  Give it another shot.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I've written joins before, but nothing this complex. For now, it works. Later when I have time, I'll actually try to figure out HOW it works.

Comment: @DRapp, I don't know if you're still following this, but I figured I'd ask before starting a completely new question. Could you clarify what group by 1,2 means in the query? I've only seen group by used with column names. I thought maybe they were column indexes (i.e. the second and third column), which would work out to be Location_Name and Location_Lat. Is that correct, or does it mean something else entirely?

Comment: @EmmyS, Group by and Order by allow the ordinal columns of the result set in lieu of actual column name.  This may come in handy if you are querying a FUNCTION( some Parms, formatted like... ) as SomeColumn and dont want to rewrite the entire thing in your group by... Ordinal is just a short-cut.

Comment: Thanks. So in this case, 1 and 2 represent which columns? Does it start with zero or one?

Comment: @EmmyS, columns are 1-based, not zero

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm so used to dealing with zero-based counts; I needed to check.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT l.location_name, l.location_lat, l.location_long, 
       d.weather_type, d.weather_value, d.weather_unit FROM gl_weather_locations l 
LEFT JOIN gl_weather_data d on l.location_lat = d.weather_lat 
**order by weather_time desc limit 3**
```

Comment: Limit 3 limits it to returning 3 records, period. I need the most recent 3 records for each location.